# Adding colours and posting in rgb

Tags: java, rgb

I am trying to get red from one colour, green from another colour and blue from another and add them to make a whole new colour. but it keeps saying that line 2 symbol can't be found, and now its saying i need a return type. what do i do?

```
 public static four (String[] args) {
       Color colour4 = new Color();
       int red = colour1.getRed();
       int green = colour2.getGreen();
       int blue = colour3.getBlue();


       System.out.println("The RGB is: ("+red+","+green+","+blue+")");
}
```

code for other colours is generally this

```
public static void second (String[] args) {
      Scanner b = new Scanner (System.in);

      System.out.println("What's the decimal?");
      int value = b.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Your decimal is"+value);

      Color colour2 = new Color(value);
      int red = colour2.getRed();
      int green = colour2.getGreen();
      int blue = colour2.getBlue();

      System.out.println("The RGB is: ("+red+","+green+","+blue+")");
}
```

Comment: What is line 2?  What is `colour1`? `colour2`? `colour3`?

Comment: Here's my whole code

Comment: show the code where you have declared colour1....

Comment: wow that looks terrible

Comment: hows that not correct?

Comment: I still don't know which line "2" is.  Also if this is your whole code then you're missing a `main` method, and you have no class definitions at all.

Comment: @getlost [`Color(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)) is valid...

Comment: okay this isn't my ENTIRE code i just posted my attempt at making the fourth colour and the code i used to get the first three colours, which was the same. line 2 in this sense would be 'Color colour4 = new Color();

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely wrong:

- The method that should be executed is always named `main` and should be `void` (you did not specify a return type).
- The reason why your compiler is having trouble with it, is because you use a variable (`colour1`, that you have not declared in the first place.
- A color does not really has a "decimal". The red channel are the eight highest bits of a 24-bit integer, the green channel are the eight bits in the middle and the blue channel are the eight lowest bits.

Possible solution:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner b = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("What's the first color decimal?");
    int value = b.nextInt();
    Color colour1 = new Color(value);

    System.out.println("What's the second color decimal?");
    value = b.nextInt();
    Color colour2 = new Color(value);

    System.out.println("What's the third color decimal?");
    value = b.nextInt();
    Color colour3 = new Color(value);

    int red = colour1.getRed();
    int green = colour2.getGreen();
    int blue = colour3.getBlue();

    Color colour4 = new Color(red,green,blue);

    //do something with colour4

    System.out.println("The RGB is: ("+red+","+green+","+blue+")"); 
}
```

Comment: okay and if I want to show the first three colors as RGB, would I just put system.out.print("The RGB is")?

Comment: No. `System.out.print(String.format("The RGB is: (%s,%s,%s)",colour1.getRed(),colour1.getGreen(),colour1.getBlue()));`